# Significance level in table gives overfull warning

Tags: tables

When I add the ** to denote significance levels, I get the overfull warning. Any advice to avoid this would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  SS
  l
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S
  l
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  SS
  l
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  SS
}

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Normal} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Student-t} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{GED} \ \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10} % center non-numerical info (A, B, ...) by placing them in braces
 & {s}  & {KLIC} & {CSL} &   & {KLIC} & {CSL} &  & {KLIC} & {CSL} \\
\midrule  % leave gap between the two rules
GARCH
  & 1 & 0.158 & 1.350 & & -0.425 & 5.336 & & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
  & 5 & 0.482 & 2.343**  & & -0.468 & 10.791 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 1.048 & 7.561 & & -0.510 & 15.779 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
GJR
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 1.228 & 6.429 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 1.350 & 8.249 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.008 & & 1.428 & 11.192 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
MS-GARCH
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.998 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.812 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.811 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: You appear to define a `tabular` environment with 24 [!] columns, yet the table itself possesses only 8 columns. Which part of the column definition is supposed to be used?

Comment: The tabular compiles correctly without the **, the errors appear when I add them.

Comment: It has 10 columns @Mico, 2 are blank columns I think the OP is not familiar with `@{}` notation.

Comment: @MellyDonald, if you remove the most of the columns you are using it still compiles, just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't say the example code compiles *typographically* correctly. For one, the "minus" symbols are rendered as simple dashes, not as typographic minus symbols.

Comment: My problem now appears to be this black box appearing next to the **, any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `table-text-space-post` can be used to account for the extra space by the postfix. The example also fixes the column specifications and the top rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=2]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-space-text-post={**}]
  l
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  l
  S
  S
}
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Normal} & &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Student-t} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{GED} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
% center non-numerical info (A, B, ...) by placing them in braces
 & {s}  & {KLIC} & {CSL} &   & {KLIC} & {CSL} &  & {KLIC} & {CSL} \\
\midrule  % leave gap between the two rules
GARCH
  & 1 & 0.158 & 1.350 & & -0.425 & 5.336 & & 0.999 & 0.999 \\
  & 5 & 0.482 & 2.343**  & & -0.468 & 10.791 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 1.048 & 7.561 & & -0.510 & 15.779 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
GJR
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 1.228 & 6.429 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.010 & & 1.350 & 8.249 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.008 & & 1.428 & 11.192 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\addlinespace
MS-GARCH
  & 1 & 0.999 & 0.998 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 5 & 0.999 & 0.812 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
  & 10 & 0.999 & 0.811 & & 0.999 & 0.999 & & 0.999 & 0.999\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW, the black box was caused by option `draft` (or the setting of length `\overfullrule`), not shown in the MWE.

---

The column header `CSL` can also be centered to the numeric values only:

```
{CSL\hphantom{**}}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant way of separating the columns instead of using a blank column?

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos You can try with `@{...}`, but the `\cmidrule`s are not making it too easy.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and wasn't pretty. That's why I asked. =/

Comment: using an `\rlap` for the asterisks would look nicer, centering the values under the column heading as they are in the other "CSL" column.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good idea, especially for the wide space between the columns groups. The updated answer centers the column header "CSL" using a different method, which can be used for narrow space between columns. Also, the `\cmidrule` keeps long enough, because it still knows about the space for the text post fix.